# Java 1.6 Swing Application Windows 7 GUI Problems

Tags: windows-7, java-6, aero

Hi I have an java Application which uses the `Borland DBSwing` Libarys to make the GUI. I compile it with `jdk 1.8`

I use this java runtime environment:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
```

I use in my win 7 machine under

`System Properties -> Advanced -> Performance Options -> Tab "Visual Effects"` the

`Adjust for best performance` like in the picture here:

[image]

Then the application **GUI works perfect**:

[image]

But if I change to `Adjust for best Appearance` the GUI makes me a lot of problems:

- It takes `hover` as `onclick`
- the colors are messed up ....

[image]

My Question is if it is possible to have your Windows 7 Desktop with Aero Display and all the other visual Effects on and only run this specific process without all the visual effects.

Or if this is not possible from a windows side if there are some flags I can give to my jvm that it deactivates all the modern visual effects from the Swing GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that I can deactivate all the modern effects in the Window with: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");`

The Problem is that I still have do deactivate windows Aero to get everything running: https://superuser.com/questions/266323/disable-aero-on-run-application

It would be nice if there is a way to disable the Windows areo effict within the java code or with a flag for the jvm